# Unable to retrieve data after using dill or pickle

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, pickle, dill

I dumped a Jupyter Notebook session using `dill.dump_session(filename)`, and at one point it told me that the disk storage was full. However, I made some space on the disk and tried again. Now, I am unable to load back the session using, `dill.load_session(filename)`.

I get the following error:

> ```
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in load_session(filename, main)
>     408         unpickler._main = main
>     409         unpickler._session = True
> --> 410         module = unpickler.load()
>     411         unpickler._session = False
>     412         main.__dict__.update(module.__dict__)
>
>  EOFError: Ran out of input
> ```

And the file (i.e. filename) is about 30 gigs in size of data.

How can I retrieve my data from the file?

BTW, I’m running all this on Google Cloud, and it’s costing me a fortune to keep the instance up and running.

I have tried using `undill`, and other `unpickle` methods.

For example I tried this:

```
 open(file, 'a').close()
      try:
     with open(file, "rb") as Score_file:
            unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(Score_file)
            scores = unpickler.load()
            return scores
```

But got this error:

> ```
>       `6         with open(file, "rb") as Score_file:
>        7             unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(Score_file);
>  ----> 8             scores = unpickler.load();
>        9 
>       10             return scores
>
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'`
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Kate Orlova

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't the answer you want to hear, but... it sounds like you may have a corrupt pickle file.  If that's the case, you can get the data back only if you edit it by hand, and can understand what the pickled strings are and how they are structured.  Note that there are some very rare cases that an object will `dump`, but not `load` -- however, it's much more likely you have a corrupt file.  Either way, the resolution is the same... a hand edit is the only way to potentially save what you have pickled.

Also, note that if you use `dump_session`, you really should use `load_session` (as it does a sequence of steps on top of a standard `load`, reversing what is done in `dump_session`) -- that's really irrelevant for the issue however, the issue likely is having an incomplete or corrupt pickle file.